# HttpWebRequest for connect to Rest web service works on the console but not on the Web Application in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to connect to a REST service with HttpWebRequest .
The following code works well in the console environment but gives a bad request error in the webapp environment. what do you think is the problem with the code?

this is my code :

**DisableSslVerification**

```
    private static void DisableSslVerification()
    {

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(
        Object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, 
        SslPolicyErrors errors)
        {
            return (true);
    };
```

**Send Get Request :**

*server = "IP:Port" ------> "123.456.789.123:443" ------> Fake ip

path = "auth_answer?param1=4bbd9199f7528a79a410c1aec26cd296&param2=e65e4628edc14d97daf96799accedeb7"*

```
   public String SendGet(String path,String server)
    {
        String url = server + path;
        String response;
        Console.WriteLine("Sending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        //---
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        req.Method = "GET";
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0";
        //---
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        //---
        using(StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
              response = stream.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return(response);
    }
```

**param1** and **param2** are used for authentication.

**program output in console app :**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyAQW.png

**webapp output :**

```
exception The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Comment: In case 400 does response's body contain any relevant information? (Like one of the provided parameter is malformed)

Comment: Tnx Peter , response body get just a bad request response in web api app and code work in console without problem and bad request error . What is different between making httpwebrequest request in console and webapp in asp.net core ? I get many difference like used Proxy property in both request and host value in Fiddler Http request header . In fiddler for consle request capturing i see host value is  just ip value but in web app host value is ip:443 . Can you describe me for this difference?

Comment: Could you please include both of the outgoing requests into your question? (If I understand correctly you had captured them with Fiddler, right?)

Comment: Yes . I capturing requests with fiddler and understand when request send in console requests sends in one ssl tunnel but in webapp multiple requests sends per multiple tunnels . I think this is my problem . Why webapp establish a tunnel per each request?